# Reload Fragment, Fragment dont call onCreateView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

i have a Fragment(C) with a ViewPager(Adapter) with 2 Fragments(A/B).
When i call the Fragment once time, they load fine.
But when i call the Fragment(C) the secend time, the Fragment A and B dont call the View onCreateView methode and the isn´t loaded.

The Fragment C is called with Fragmetnmanger:

```
FragmentC fragment = new FragmentC();
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.adressenmdf_detail_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Fragment C

```
 public BelegeDetails(){

}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_belege_details, container, false);
    //TODO Actionbar noch anpassen
    //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



    viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    setupTabIcons();
```

The Setups from Fragment C

```
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this.getFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(new BelegeDetails1(),"Details" );
    adapter.addFragment(new BelegeDetailsPos(), "Positionen");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
private void setupTabIcons() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_belege);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);

    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

The Fragment A BelegDetails1 und the Fragment B BelegDetailsPos are normal Fragment Classes like:

```
  public BelegeDetails1() {
    // Required empty public constructor

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState.......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing this:

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this.getFragmentManager());
```

with:

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

As you are nesting fragments, you need to use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`